# How to position adorner for TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

I create adorner containing TextBlock.
This TextBlock overlaps adorned TextBox.
The problem is that starting positions of the text for these controls are not the same.
How can I align TextBlock to achieve a match of text positions?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the obvious of adjusting the margin of the TextBlock that is in the adorner layer, there is another possible approach that comes to mind.  Without knowing what your real goal is (besides just positioning text over the TextBox) its hard to say if this would be helpful, but here goes.

You could [use a VisualBrush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433840/718325) that consists of the TextBlock that you were using in the adorner layer (this technique will *not* use the adorner layer).  Then apply that VisualBrush to the background of the TextBox.  This will position the text exactly in your TextBox.  Of course, this technique is mostly useful when the TextBox is empty, so that only the text from the VisualBrush's TextBlock is visible (rather than having any additional text from the TextBox also visible).

I have used this technique for showing "hint text" when a TextBox is empty (shown here with a possibly dubious combination of an ErrorTemplate and the hint text, but you get the idea).  The "0 to 159" text is a TextBlock in the VisualBrush that gets applied to the TextBox's background when its Text property is empty:

[image: Hint Text shown using a VisualBrush]

Perhaps with more information about your goals we can suggest other approaches as well.

Comment: Yes, hint text is the goal. I considered VisualBrush but it's not acceptable to change TextProperty because of the binding.

Comment: @voroninp I'm not sure I understand.  Using the `VisualBrush` technique allows you put the hint text in a `Brush` which gets applied to the **background** property of the `TextBox`, so you don't mess with the actual `TextBox.TextProperty`.  Because of this, its worked fine for times when I've used this technique with bound `TextBoxes`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand what you mean.  The problem here is that the style of the visual is not the same as the style of the text in a TextBox. Text alignment can differ, size of the font and etc. I hope you agree that it's more eye pleasant to see the blinking cursor exactly at the first letter. And if user just types the same text as the hint text does not move it only changes its color. I know this is a kind of perfectionism =)