# WPF How do i set text as textbox's background in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, textbox

is it even possible to set text as textbox's background in code behind?

```
 textbox.Background = ??
```

Or do i have to use a TextBlock and assign text to the TextBock then i add TextBlock as TextBox's background? but how do i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add a hint text to WPF textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425618/how-can-i-add-a-hint-text-to-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `VisualBrush` to draw elements on a Background of another element

Example:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left"> 
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <TextBox Text="StackOverflow"/>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </TextBox.Background>
</TextBox>
```

Or in code behind

```
textBox.Background = new VisualBrush(new TextBox { Text = "StackOverflow" })
{
    AlignmentX = AlignmentX.Left,
    Stretch = Stretch.None
};
```

Result:

[image]