# Styling a WPF Passwordbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, passwordbox

I'm currently trying to do the following:
If no password is entered a text "Password" should be shown.

But with my template no password is shown, and if i'm using a decorator or a scrollviewer i can't change the color of the text.

Do you have any ideas to achieve this?

Here's my styling code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}" x:Key="Password">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PasswordBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <PasswordBox Background="{StaticResource BrushDark}" Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BrushBorderInput}" BorderThickness="1"/>
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Password"
                            Margin="5,0,5,0"
                            Foreground="#ff808080"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            x:Name="UserMessage"
                            Visibility="Hidden"/>
                        <!--<ScrollViewer Foreground="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" Background="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>-->
                        <!--<Decorator TextBlock.Foreground="White" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>-->
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="Tag" Value=""/>
                                <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="False"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="UserMessage" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/q/7425618/2530848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create custom `ControlTemplate` for `PasswordBox` or `TextBox` you need to put `ScrollViewer` named `x:Name="PART_ContentHost` instead of inner `PasswordBox`

From [PasswordBox Syles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468216(v=vs.110).aspx)

> PART_ContentHost - A visual element that can contain a FrameworkElement. The text of the PasswordBox is displayed in this element.

And change `Foreground` as another `Setter` in you `Style`. Also, as a side node, I would do the same with `Background` and use `TemplateBinding` in your `ControlTemplate`. This will give more flexibility and allow you to change `Background` and/or `Foreground` manually without changing `ControlTemplate`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}" x:Key="Password">
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource BrushTextNormal}" />
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BrushDark}"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
               <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" .../>
               <TextBlock .../>               
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <!-- removed -->
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```