# Why PasswordBox is not getting a rounded corner style?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, rounded-corners, wpf-style, passwordbox

I wrote a style code for `TextBox` rounded corner and it worked. But When I tried the same code just changing the `TargetType` field to `PasswordBox` It didn't work for `PasswordBox`.
Thanks in advance.

This is my style code:

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxTemplate" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#525252"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="PasswordBoxTemplate" TargetType="PasswordBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#525252"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

This is my XAML style binding code:

```
<PasswordBox Style="{DynamicResource PasswordBoxTemplate}" Name="txtPassword" FontSize="18"/>
```

[image: This is how my window look after inserting the style code.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238149/styling-a-wpf-passwordbox I think that this may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PasswordBox` is special in that it resets the `Border` style. It is implemented this way. What you can do is you can copy the default style of the `PasswordBox` and adapt the corner radius  directly.

```
<Style x:Key="PasswordBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
   <Setter Property="PasswordChar" Value="●"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="#525252"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFABAdB3"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
   <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
   <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
   <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
   <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
               <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                  <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="border" Value="0.56"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
               </Trigger>
               <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF569DE5"/>
               </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <MultiTrigger>
         <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled" Value="true"/>
            <Condition Property="IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
         </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
         <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
      </MultiTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```