# How to set the hint text and hint text color of textbox in wpf xaml?

Tags: c#

I want to make the hint text and set the hint text color in xaml textbox.
Is there a way to set the hint text and hint text color in textbox at xaml file directly?
Please let me know the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a hint text to WPF textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425618/how-can-i-add-a-hint-text-to-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use MaterialDesignThemes. Download the NuGet package and use it as follow:

```
xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" 

<TextBox materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Floating Hint" Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

You also need to make the following changes in your App.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Dark.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

[MaterialDesign Getting Started](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/)

Comment: Is there no way to make hint text without using material design?
I made one style in windows.resource and use that as a Style.
Is there a way to use 2 styles in one textbox?
Anyways, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I think its possible to make the hint text by yourself (as a Style), its just a easy solution. You dont need to reinvent the weel ; )

Comment: Please let me know the way how to set hint text by manual. Thanks in advance.