# How to add a materialDesign:Hint to a TextBox in code

Tags: c#, wpf, material-design-in-xaml

```
<TextBox md:HintAssist.Hint="Dinheiro" md:HintAssist.Background="#FFF"  />
```

How do i create a TextBox with a hint like that in code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add a hint text to WPF textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425618/how-can-i-add-a-hint-text-to-wpf-textbox)

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetHint(textBox, "Dinheiro");
MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.HintAssist.SetBackground(textBox, Brushes.White);
```