# Changing text of Textbox, when IsFocused=false

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How can I make following functionality:

if Textbox is not focused, and user didn't type any text there, textbox should have default value, something like *Enter Name Here...*. If user click on that textbox this label should dissapear.

Appreciate any help.

This is what I have so far. But this is control template. I think it's not so helpfull in this question but anyway.

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="TextBoxBaseControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="LightGray"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ScrollViewer Margin="5 0 0 0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" TargetName="Bd"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Width" Value="Auto">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Height" Value="Auto">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384264/how-do-you-implement-default-text-for-a-search-box-in-wpf ?

Comment: ups, I didn't find that discussion. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One nice looking way is to make your default text a watermark. I assume this is going to be in a UserControl so here is my implementation

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBackground" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkForeground" Color="LightSteelBlue" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBorder" Color="Indigo" />

    <utilities:TextInputToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextInputToVisibilityConverter" />
    <utilities:VisibilityToColorConverter x:Key="VisibilityToColorConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="MsgHeader1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="18,0,19,134" Width="308" Text="Enter Name Here..." Foreground="{StaticResource brushWatermarkForeground}" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="White">
            <TextBlock.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TextInputToVisibilityConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="MsgHeader2" Path="Text.IsEmpty" />
                    <Binding ElementName="MsgHeader2" Path="IsFocused" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Visibility>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="MsgHeader2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="{Binding ElementName=MsgHeader1, Path=Visibility, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityToColorConverter}}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBorder}" Margin="18,0,19,134" Text="{Binding MessageHeader}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="308" Height="46" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Grid>
```

Obviously you have to define your own ValueConverters (mine are my own utilities xmlns), but these are easy enough. This will also give you a data binding for your text once you have some that has been entered.